# Full Calender view download as PDF?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using Full-calendar script to show calendar with events on my website.

How can i download the view of calendar as PDF?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rahul.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: No, i have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jspdf (A HTML5 client-side solution for generating PDFs) here https://parall.ax/products/jspdf